# Nested CSS statements

Tags: css

Can we do nested CSS statements? Instead of repeating classes like:

```
.hello .world1 {}
.hello .world2 {}
```

We do something like:

```
.hello {
   .world1 {}
   .world2 {}
}
```

Is similar thing possible in CSS/CSS3?

Comment: It's not possible with CSS.
but there are some preprocessor which might help. Sass and LESS are good preprocessors, you can check those out.

Comment: A tear was just shed.

Comment: You could look into LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in CSS but you could do that using SASS.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine child elements using: **Child Selector**

The child selector selects all elements that are the immediate children of a specified element.

The following example selects all "p" elements that are immediate children of a  element:

Example:

```
div > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```